# encriptar dato usando encrypt laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, axios

hola estoy intentando encriptar un dato que traigo a través una consulta con axios
y pintarla en la vista con con vue.

quiero usar el tipo de cifrado usando con php laravel

`<a href="...{{encrypt($id_clase)}}}">...</a>`

pero quiero usar el cifrado cuando el dato lo traigo desde  mi consulta axios y pintarlo con vue

```
<ul id="example-2">
  <li v-for="(clase, index) in clases">
    <a v-bind:href="'...'+clase.id_clase"}}}>...</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

quiero poder encriptar el dato 'clase.id_clase' con el tipo de cifrado como lo hago en php

los datos los traigo con axios y vue por que la vista tiene filtros para consulta

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la duda?

Comment: como usar el cifrado encrypt de php pero en vue

Comment: Manda el dato encriptado desde el back end ya que si es vue no puedes usar blade, como supongo que es una coleccion de datos puedes usar map o algo mas estructurado seria un resource